# What is so dangerous about Wormhole affix?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, there is an affix called "Wormhole" that causes you to be moved from one side of a pink circle to another after a second or two of delay.

This seems to be by far the most benign monster affix!  Who cares if you get shifted from one spot to another?  More often than not, it actually takes me out of a dangerous floor covered in fire or acid.  Am I missing some hidden danger here?  Are there some classes and playstyles that are actually threatened by this affix?

See [this](http://www.diablowiki.net/Wormhole_(Elite_Affix)) for reference.

Comment: It can be stressful for melee characters.

Comment: @Humungus Its stressfull for ranged class aswell, I play DH and I have to pay attention to those everytime because you dont want to be teleported in the middle of everything

Comment: Most stressful for hardcore characters.

Comment: Depends on how many frozen pulses, poison puddles, walls, molten fire, and everything else is on the screen.  On its own, it's not bad, but a poorly placed wormhole with multiple elite packs can be lethal.

Comment: @Sterno Everything's stressful for hardcore characters.

Comment: sometimes I get a graphical glitch (or maybe there's just too much crap on the ground) and I can't see them, super annoying.  Every once in a while too it puts you in a really out of the way spot, such as on top of a cliff and you have to back track a long way to get back.

Comment: Normally, they are just amusing. But sometimes, they are deadly. I had one cause me to die in a greater rift because it locked me in the middle of several champion mobs, and another freakish time I was jailed on one only to have it port me to a corpse explosion. I haven't noticed taking damage directly from the wormhole though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "danger" is entirely situational, depending on what class you're playing, how many enemies there are and where you're tp'd to. But as [Humungus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178153/what-is-so-dangerous-about-wormhole-affix/178161#comment241916_178153) said, it's generally more annoying than anything, especially for melee classes.

Comment: There's also a small amount of Arcane damage taken when you go through a wormhole, but in the vast majority of situations the damage isn't going to really affect you.